# How to disallow GNU screen from making change to my putty window title

Tags: gnu-screen, putty, window-title

Currently whenever I open a screen session from within PuTTY, the window title of the PuTTY window changes to "screen". I would like to prevent this from happening.

Please let me know what is the way to do it. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Please note that I'm **NOT** asking about title of various sessions within screen (which can be set with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd>). I'm asking about PuTTY's window title.

Answer (score 9):

http://malektips.com/putty-prevent-remote-changing-title.html#.U_SDEWPnGhI

I figured it out myself. The tip in the above link helps.

*excerpt from that URL*

> Via [escape sequences](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html), some remote computers have the ability to change
>   the titles of client windows of applications such as [PuTTY](http://malektips.com/putty_help_and_tips.html). Examples
>   include a logon script that changes the PuTTY window title to the
>   user's login name, or a shell prompt that continually changes PuTTY's
>   window title to contain the name of the current remote client
>   directory.
>
> While sometimes these window title changes are desired, in other
>   situations you would rather define a window title and have it stick
>   without worrying about having it changed by the remote system. Thus
>   you can lock the window title:
>
> 1. Open PuTTY.
> 2. Click on the "Session" link in the left pane.
> 3. In the right pane, click "Default Settings", or a defined session, then the "Load" button.
> 4. Expand the "Terminal" tree in the left pane.
> 5. Click the "Features" link in the left pane.
> 6. In the right pane, check "Disable remote-controlled window title changing".
>
>    [image: ss #1]
> 7. Click on the "Session" link in the left pane.
> 8. Choose the session name you chose in #3, or "Default Settings".
> 9. Click the "Save" button.
>
> Note that if you change the default settings, you will still need to
>   change the settings for each saved session.
>
> Return to the [Putty](http://malektips.com/putty_help_and_tips.html) page.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! This is a [questions and answers site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [do not post an answer which is just a link to another site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). At least summarize the content in your post. See [How to Answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more tips on writing answers.

Comment: I've recapped the A here to show you how you can do this in the future, if you ever need to do something similar. As long as you provide attributions to the original contents it's perfectly fine to excerpt pre-existing content here. Please mark this as the accepted A so that everyone knows your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will make sure that i post excerpts from the links if i ever do so again. 

I am at the moment unable to accept my own answer as it says "You can accept your own answer tomorrow".